# Use chatGPT, for convert CSIDE to Plantuml, do not give what I want of large text

Tags: uml

I explain the error:

I have a large code divided in 18 parts, in CSIDE that represents two tables (header and lines) that I divided into 18 parts because it is very long, and then I told chatGPT that I wanted to pass only the tables, fields and key relationships to PLANTUML CODE.

But it says that since it is a very long text, it cannot perform this operation, and it only gives me examples. I made more than 14 query attempts to create a PLANTUML CODE, with all the “tables, fields and key relationships”, but It only tells me that it is not possible and only gives me real examples, and that I manually complete what is missing.

So to solve this problem.
How could I do what I previously wanted?

Any recommendations, or maybe by pay version or API of chatGPT i can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple solution: use a **real** tool for this. ChatGPT is a toy.

Comment: Hello Alejandro, could you please guide me on the tools I can use to achieve my goal? While ChatGPT performs well with a small example, but does not give correct answers if do the same with a larger example, particularly one exceeding 6000 lines of CSIDE Code, dividied in 18 parts.